# Monitor Blinking

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, video

I was a Debian user, but for some reason, after I installed Arch Linux, my monitor started to blink. It happens even on text terminals (C-F1 etc), but only after gdm starts. Any idea on what could be happening and how to fix it?

I installed very few programs: vim, xorg, xf86-video-ati, gdm, xorg, fluxbox, vim, sudo and chromium. I installed xf86-video-ati based on the output of lspci:

```
[tata@spock ~]$ lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RS690 [Radeon X1200 Series]
```